# How can I create dynamic variable names in JSTL or an alternative

Tags: sql, jsp, jstl

I need to use JSTL and ideally I think an Array would be better as I need to create a bunch of variables with a value using SQL data from data.rows but I need to get the variable name from the data using row.type. However I am finding this hard because you cannot define a session variable using "${row.type}" as it raises an exception. It must be a concrete variable name. I would have thought an array would be best but no idea how to do this from my SQL JSTL query:

```
<sql:query var="data">
    SELECT type, balance FROM Account WHERE account_number IN (SELECT account_number FROM CustomerAccount WHERE customer_number = "${sessionScope.CustomerNumber}");
</sql:query>
```

This is the code:

```
<c:forEach var="row" items="${data.rows}">
    <c:set var="${row.type}" value="${row.balance}" scope="session" />
</c:forEach>
```

Any help or tips would be brilliant! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
   <c:forEach var="row" items="${data.rows}" varStatus="status">
     <c:set var="rowType${status.count}" value="${row.balance}" scope="session" />
  </c:forEach>
```

so it will create like rowType1, rowType2 and etc and its corresponding value will be balance.
Here,

```
${status.count}
```

is like an index in for loop.

Or try this out,

```
   <c:forEach var="row" items="${data.rows}">
     <c:set var="rowType${row.type}" value="${row.balance}" scope="session" />
  </c:forEach>
```

Comment: `<c:set>` does not accept dynamic variables to it's `var` attribute, so this will not work.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Spring WebMVC you can use their `eval`-tag to dynamically assign values:

```
<spring:eval expression="row.balance" var="rowType${status.count}" scope="session"/>
```

I'm not sure if session scope is really the right thing to do but that depends on your application, of course. See http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/spring.tld.html#spring.tld.eval for details about the `eval` tag.